# Python3 open image with dialog box in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, file-upload

Am on a course in python3 from a book and it doesn't have any explaination on way i get this error when trying to open a image with a dialog bog (file explorer), to be clear the image can be open by using Image.open() but when i do open it with the file explore i get this:

```
"C:\Users\Yoant\Documents\Python Program\Programs\Tkinter-Course\Open File dialog box\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Yoant/Documents/Python Program/Programs/Tkinter-Course/Open File dialog box/main.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Yoant\Documents\Python Program\Programs\Tkinter-Course\Open File dialog box\main.py", line 16, in <module>
    my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
  File "C:\Users\Yoant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2900, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
  File "C:\Users\Yoant\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 246: character maps to <undefined>
```

```
# this is my code below:

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("File Dialog box")

# Return the name and location of the file.
root.filename = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir="/Pictures", title="select a file", filetypes=(("png files", "*.jpg"),("all file", "*.*")))

# Display dir of file selected
my_lbl = Label(root, text=root.filename).pack()

# Display image
my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(root.filename))
my_lbl2 = Label(image=my_img).pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `askopenfilename()` instead of `askopenfile()`.

Comment: i did a similaire change, i replaced root.filename to root.filename.name, but yeah i t hink that your methode is cleaner, thanks alot.